# Integer pointer to char array

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am working on an application (C++ language on visual studio) where all the strings are referred with integer pointer.

For example, the class I am using has this integer pointer to the data and a variable for size.

```
{
    ..
    ..
    unsigned short int *pData;
    int iLen
}
```

I would like to know

1. Are there any advantages of using `int` pointer instead of `char` pointer?

   After thinking a lot, I suspect that the reason may be to avoid the application crash which may happen if the char pointer is used without a null termination. But i am not 100% sure.
2. During debugging, how can we check the content of the pointer, where the content is a char array or string (on Visual studio).

   I can only see the address when I check the content during debugging. because of this i am facing difficulty in debugging.

   Using `printf` would work to display the content but I can't do it in all places.

   i am suspecting that the reason for using integer pointer may be to avoid the application crash which may happen if the char pointer is used without a null termination. But i am not 100% sure.

may be to avoid such programmatic errors it is taken as integer pointer.

the class i am using has this integer pointer to the data and a variable for size.

{

..

..

unsigned int *pData;

int iLen

}

Please correct me if you think this can not be the reason.

Comment: *Why* are you using an int pointer?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Fix the data type in the code.

Comment: I don't see how this would achieve anything useful in either C or C++ (also please decide which language you are using, they have sufficient differences to require different treatment)

Comment: Not sure if this doesn't violate [strict aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing).

Comment: I think that the codebase might be using `int` as if it was `wchar_t` (wide character, for non-ASCII (unicode))

Comment: When debugging, you could put the explicit cast in the watch window, like `(char*)var`. But you would have to do it manually for each variable you want to inspect, no tooltip for them.

Comment: i am not using int pointer. its an existing application which provides the class for string usage. which internally uses int pointer. i cant change that code.

Comment: To be very specific it is  of type "unsigned short int"

Comment: If they are wide strings then this is correct behaviour (in the MS comipler,, `wchar_t` is a typedef for `unsigned short int`)

Comment: You would get better answers by posting a code sample

Comment: enO esuluoceb d ot ekamuoy ts rgnirdne enaid-ssnepetned. (One use could be to make your string endianess-dependent.)

Comment: If you dont need something, why feel the need to use it?

Comment: I think M.M hit the spot. Most GUI applications and increasingly console applications have unicode support and potentially need something longer than char for that.

Answer (score 1):

Please let us know which language you're using so that we can help you a bit better. As for your questions:

1. There is no benefit of using an `int` array vs. `char` array. In fact having an integer array takes up more space (if each int represents its own character). This is because a char takes up one byte where an integer takes up four.
2. As for printing things when debugging I'm not a master of visual studio since I haven't used it in some time but most modern IDEs allow you to cast things before you print them. For example in lldb you can do `po (char)myIntArray[0]` (po stands for print). In visual studio [writing a custom visualizer should do the trick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx).

Comment: The standard does not actually specify the size of either `char` or `int`, it is compiler dependent (although the sizes you mentioned are correct for most modern compilers)

Comment: Sorry to miss out the language used. it is C++ & C. i have edited my question to include language. Thanks for the answer. i ll look through the custom visualizer.

Comment: @Sagar I already commented on your question (and this is what Majster wanted to have clarification on) that C and C++ are different programming languages that require different treatment (and different code). Please decide which one you are using.

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, I know that it's compiler dependent and it's good that you pointed this out. I'm using the "standard" values only for the sake of simplicity and ease of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, but if you wanted to store an EOF character in your string for some reason, you would need a pointer to int.

Answer (score 1):

MS Visual Studio often uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) to store strings. UTF-16 requires a 16-bit data type, your application uses `unsigned short` for that, while a more correct name would be `uint16_t` (or maybe `wchar_t`, but I am not sure about that).

Another way to store strings uses [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8); if you use this way, use a pointer to `char` (not convenient) or `std::string` (more convenient). However, you don't have any choice here; you are not going to change how your application stores strings (it's probably too tedious).

To view your UTF-16-encoded string, use a dedicated [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx). For example, in a quick-watch window, enter:

```
object->pData,su
```

instead of just

```
object->pData
```